# View Create send IEnumerable to Controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

View

```
@model IEnumerable<MyMixtapezServerCodeHomePage.Models.album>

@for(int i=0;i<userchoiceIndex;i++)
{
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.artist)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.artist)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.artist)
    </div>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<album> album)
{
}
```

Is it possible? I want to create a multiple values to database in a faster and easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all answers, this informations did get to a single point that worked for me.

```
@model IEnumerable<MyMixtapezServerCodeHomePage.Models.album>
@using (Html.BeginForm("FeatureSystem", "album", FormMethod.Post))

<th>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
</th>

@{var item = @Model.ToList();}
@for (int count = 0; count < @Model.Count(); count++){
    <td>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => item[count].name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => item[count].name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item[count].name)
        </div>
</td>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult FeatureSystem(IEnumerable<album> albums)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but not like that.

First off, create a model that'll hold your Albums, like so:

```
public class AlbumsModel
{
    public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

Then do the following in your view. Note my use of a `for` loop, this is so the `name` attributes of the items are in sync and model binding can easily resolve the collection on post.

```
@model AlbumsModel

@for(int i=0; i<Model.Albums.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.Albums[i].artist)
   </div>
   <div class="editor-field">
       @Html.EditorFor(m=> m.Albums[i].artist)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Albums[i].artist)
   </div>
}
```

Then have your `Post` controller action be:

```
[HttpPost]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create(AlbumsModel model)
{
    foreach(Album album in model.Albums)
    {
        //do your save here
    }
    //redirect or return a view here
}
```

Comment: Whitout use IEnumerable I get this menssage 

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[MyMixtapezServerCodeHomePage.Models.album]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyMixtapezServerCodeHomePage.Models.AlbumsModel'.

Comment: @LucasRodriguesSena It sounds like you haven't changed **both** your action method and your view to use the `AlbumsModel`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this on your form view, you have to set the index of the collection:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyMixtapezServerCodeHomePage.Models.album>

@for (int i=0; i<userchoiceIndex; i++)
{
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].artist)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].artist)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].artist)
    </div>
}
```

on your controller just do something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<album> album)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
       // persist and redirect... whatever
    }
    return View(album);
}
```

Take a look at this article: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx